# Copy a file in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, csv, copy, filefield

I would like to copy a file from my computer to another specified path. The file has to be chosen by the user with a `file_field` and the destination is already hard-coded. How can I do that ? Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd use [FileUtils::cp](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/fileutils/1.9.2/FileUtils%3acp), but beware of path mangling via `../../<file>`. For that, you can use [expand_path](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/File.expand_path) and then check if the resulting path begin matches your jail.